# importing .scss with ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, sass

I'm new to react, I'm trying to import SCSS files into my CSS style sheet but the following error appears

I'm trying to apply this UI Kit to react application https://github.com/wfp/ui
and here is the instruction on how to use it [enter link description here](https://cdn.wfp.org/guides/ui/v1.2.1/docs/?path=/story/documentation-getting-started--html-usage)

```
Failed to compile
./node_modules/@wfp/ui/source/globals/scss/styles.scss
Module build failed: Syntax Error 

(30:1) Unknown word

  28 | 
  29 | @import 'text-gradient';
> 30 | //@import '../grid/grid';
     | ^
  31 | 
  32 | //-------------------------
```

here are some codes
in App.css

```
     @import '../node_modules/@wfp/ui/source/globals/scss/styles.scss'; 

    .App {
      text-align: center;
    }
```

here is part of style.scss that I'm importing

```
//-------------------------
//  Global
//-------------------------

$css--font-face: true !default;
$css--helpers: true !default;
$css--body: true !default;
//$css--use-experimental-grid: false !default;
//$css--use-experimental-grid-fallback: false !default;
$css--use-layer: true !default;
$css--reset: true !default;
$css--typography: true !default;

@import 'colors';
@import 'vars';
@import 'mixins';
@import 'layout';
@import 'layer';
@import 'rtl';
@import 'spacing';
@import 'typography';
@import 'import-once';
@import 'css--reset';
@import 'css--font-face';
@import 'css--helpers';
@import 'css--body';
@import 'css--typography';

@import 'text-gradient';
//@import '../grid/grid';

//-------------------------
// ☠️  Manage deprecations
//-------------------------
```

please tell me what do you like to see to update the question

Comment: May I ask you to share more code details

Comment: I updated the question with more detailed, Thank you ...

Comment: Did you install **node-sass** package inside your dependencies?

Comment: I just installed it, it doesn't make any difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what I did to resolve this is to import the CDN link

```
 <link
  rel="stylesheet"
  type="text/css"
  href="https://cdn.wfp.org/guides/ui/v1.1.16/assets/css/styles.min.css"
/>
```

in the index.html
I couldn't resolve the import scss issue but this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Below steps should work with you

1- run  **npm install node-sass**

2- in you App.js

08-07-2019 Code updated @WFP styles applied

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import "../node_modules/@wfp/ui/source/globals/scss/styles.scss";

function App() {
  return (
<div className="App">
  <div id="container" style={{ flexBasis: "auto" }}>
    <div className="storybook-readme-story">
      <div>
        <button
          tabindex="0"
          className="wfp--btn wfp--btn--secondary"
          type="button"
        >
          Cancel
        </button>
        <button
          tabindex="0"
          className="wfp--btn wfp--btn--primary"
          type="button"
        >
          Submit
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: the error is gone but it's not reading and style it's blanked without any style